# jQuery widget: restricting widgets to selected tags

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to restrict construction of my widget to `<table>` elements only. This was easy in my pre-widget version of a plugin, where I was testing `tagName`.

```
if (this.element[0].tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'table')
```

If the `tagName` was not suitable I was just returning the jQuery object to ensure chainability.

How would I go about it on the top of the widget factory?

Comment: inside the widget constructor you can test the element and raise an exeption if it does not match the table constraint.

Comment: still awake? if somebody puts effort into answering your question you should appreciate it.

Comment: Good Man, first off, I'm not spending all my life at my computer, which means I don't test every snippet right away. Secondly, not knowing anything about my life, you'd probably be ashamed to have called for attention. Thirdly, thanks for your code, it started to work as soon as I changed the function name to `toLowerCase`. All the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

taking the sample from http://jqueryui.com/widget/

```
$.widget( "custom.mywidget", {

// the constructor
_create: function() {
   if(this.element.tagName.toLower() !== 'table') throw "mywidget requires tableelement";
```